# Laravel ajax request not working on https

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, heroku

i'm using heroku to host my laravel project

and i used some ajax request on my code

it's work fine on local machine

but not working on heroku https domain
but it's work on http domain

```
$("div select#Wilaya").change(function () {
    $apiWilaya = "/api/region/?wilaya=" + $(this).val();
    $.getJSON($apiWilaya, function (data) {
        // Clean select options
        $("div select#Daira,div select#Commune").find('option').remove("option[value]").end().find('option[hidden]').prop('selected', true);
        // FETCH ALL DAIRA'S
        $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
            $("div select#Daira").append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.daira_id).text(entry.daira_nom));
        });
    });
    //enable Daira disable Commune select
    $("div select#Daira").prop('disabled', false);
    $("div select#Commune").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

and also

```
function newMessage() {
        message = $(".message-input input").val();
        if ($.trim(message) == '' || !$('#contacter_disc').val()) {
            return false;
        }
        disc_id = $('#contacter_disc').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/home/messages/send",
            data: {disc_id: disc_id, message: message},
            success: function (data) {
                $('.message-input input').val(null);
                $(".messages ul").load("/home/messages/fetch", {get: 'messages', disc_id: disc_id}, function () {
                    $(".messages").animate({scrollTop: 90000000}, "fast");
                });
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

[https request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILwSZ.png)

[http request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bqXm.png)

Comment: Strange, you got a 301 redirect on your https request.. Is it the same for everything or only your API? if only the API you may have a deeper look into your API middlewares

Comment: on all pages that are requested by ajax .. load() ...

Answer (score 0):

i have found the problem url's should not end with /

```
$("div select#Wilaya").change(function () {
$apiWilaya = "/api/region?wilaya=" + $(this).val();
$.getJSON($apiWilaya, function (data) {
    // Clean select options
    $("div select#Daira,div select#Commune").find('option').remove("option[value]").end().find('option[hidden]').prop('selected', true);
    // FETCH ALL DAIRA'S
    $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
        $("div select#Daira").append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.daira_id).text(entry.daira_nom));
    });
});
//enable Daira disable Commune select
$("div select#Daira").prop('disabled', false);
$("div select#Commune").prop('disabled', true);
```

});